# Social Login Facebook integration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i Integrate Facebook social login i create an app type=consumer when i do my configuration of app and turn it to live  It displays this message in setting "Your app has standard access to public_profile. To use Facebook Login, switch public_profile to advanced access. Get Advanced Access" to get advance access you need to do business verification  iam facing this problem due to this without admin i login from anyother id of facebook it says app feature not available iam integrating it on laravel

i tried verfyingthe account but of course this is for my personal work hence can't do business verification is it anyother possible way?